# A right proper numpy way to create flat list of indices into an array

Tags: python, numpy

Okay, this is super basic, which unfortunately means that searching for it gives a bajillion hits that all do something different and / or more complex.

Consider this code:

```py
shape = (10, 20)
indices = []
for i in range(shape[0]):
    for j in range(shape[1]):
        indices.append([i, j])
```

or alternatively `indices = itertools.product(range(10), range(20)).`

Now, I feel like there *must* be a simple numpy function that does the same? Something like

`indices = np.indices_into_shape((10, 20))`

Most of the index-generating functions I can find via search generate multiple arrays, like in `meshgrid` or `ix_`.

Comment: You could stack [np.indices](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.indices.html).

Comment: What do you plan on doing with the indices after this? It's dollars to donuts that you can get away with broadcasting without having to expand out all the indices.

Comment: `list(np.ndindex((3,4)))` is a `numpy` equivalent to the `itertools.product`.  But why should there be something better?  There isn't much need for such a list (or (n,2) array) in efficient `numpy` computing.  We want to let `numpy` do the iteration over elements in compiled code, not with iteration over a list of tuples.  `meshgrid` is the original index producer.

Comment: Why do you want a list of 200 tuples?  What's wrong with 2 (10,20) arrays?  Or maybe a (2,10,20) or (10,20,2) array?  Wouldn't you like to retain the (10,20) structure in some way or other?  Admittedly (200,2) can be easily reshaped

Comment: From the docs - a whole set of index generating functions: https://numpy.org/doc/1.18/reference/routines.indexing.html#generating-index-arrays

Comment: Thank you for the answers and replies everyone. Doesn't have to be tuples exactly. Usecase is weird third party C++ code that eventually needs stuff in a single flat list. But I'll see if I _really_ need it or not.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can stack meshgrids:

```
np.dstack(np.meshgrid(np.arange(10), np.arange(20), indexing='ij')).reshape(-1, 2)
```

Answer (score 1):

One way would be

```
np.argwhere(np.broadcast_to(True,(3,4)))
# array([[0, 0],
#        [0, 1],
#        [0, 2],
#        [0, 3],
#        [1, 0],
#        [1, 1],
#        [1, 2],
#        [1, 3],
#        [2, 0],
#        [2, 1],
#        [2, 2],
#        [2, 3]])
```

another (similar to @MadPhysicist's)

```
np.c_[np.unravel_index(np.arange(3*4),(3,4))]
```